# Empty object in post request Express.JS

Tags: html, node.js, express

I'm working with Express *v^4.18.2*, I have some routing and controller files and an html form with post method. When I make the post, I try to get the server to show me the req.body sent in the request through the console, but I get an empty object. It should be noted that I am following a tutorial and I do it step by step. Could someone with more knowledge of Express tell me what is going on?

Routes.js

```
import { Router } from "express";
import dashBoardObject from "../Controller/DashboardsController.js";
import { DashboardContoroller} from "../Controller/DashboardsController.js";

const router = Router(); 

const { formDashboardController,
        postFormDashboardController,
        putDashboardContoller
    } = dashBoardObject;

router
   .get('/DashBoard', DashboardContoroller)

   .get('/DashBoard/createdDasboard', formDashboardController)


router
   .post('/DashBoard/createdDasboard', postFormDashboardController)


router
   .put('/DashBoard/updateDashboard', putDashboardContoller)


export default router;
```

As you can see, in the routes I try to destruct the object that I get from the controller.

Controller.js

```
const dashBoardObject = {};

export const DashboardContoroller= (req, res) =>{
    res.send(`indicators/Indicators`);
} 

dashBoardObject.formDashboardController = (req, res) =>{
    res.render(`indicators/Indicators`);   
}

dashBoardObject.postFormDashboardController = (req, res) =>{
    // let values = Object.values();
    console.log(`request: ${req.body}`);
    res.send(`<h3> CREATED!  ${req.body} </h3>`);
} 

dashBoardObject.putDashboardContoller = (req, res) =>{
    res.send(`<h3> UPDATED!  </h3>`);
}

export default dashBoardObject;
```

HTML

```
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center;">
    <div>
        <form action="/DashBoard/createdDasboard" method="POST">
        <div class="mb-2 row">
            <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Titulo</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Titulo"  type="text" autofocus>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="mb-2 row">
            <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Titulo</label>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control" name="Title" placeholder="Titulo" type="text">
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="mb-2 row">

            <label for="" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">enviar</label>
                <div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" >Actualizar</button>
                </div>
            </div>



    </form>
    </div>
```

This is what I get in the browser:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If req.body is empty, you should add a middleware on top of your router:

```
router.use(express.urlencoded())
```

Also, to correctly show the object in the html response:

```
res.send(`<h3> CREATED!  ${JSON.stringify(req.body)} </h3>`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below if you are passing JSON as a POST request

```js
app.use(express.json())
```